# Is there a more idiomatic expression than "the more he becomes into x"?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

Is there a more idiomatic expression than "the more he becomes into x"? I was trying to form a sentence, but I couldn't find the right words. I know there's the expression "the more x he becomes" as in "the more human he becomes", but that expression doesn't work unless x is an adjective. So for some case you need to find an alternate expression and that's where "the more he becomes into x", but it doesn't sound idiomatic at all.

For example:

> The more a magician uses lycanthropy spells, the more he becomes into
>   a werewolf.

How would you rephrase the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just say "...the more he becomes a werewolf."

The expression "be into something", means to be very interested in it, or a fan.

> John is really into tennis, he plays every day after school.
>   If you are into wine, you should try some Chilean merlot.

The magician isn't "becoming into werewolves"; he is becoming a werewolf.

Comment: Or he could be ***turning*** *into a werewolf*. But either *becoming* or *into* needs to be changed or removed in this context.